# ¿Cómo evitar que new lance excepciones para usar excepciones creadas por mí en C++?

Tags: c++, excepciones

He estado intentanto usar `new` con `std::nothrow` para que en caso de error no lance sus propias excepciones y poder usar excepciones creadas por mi con mensajes personalizados, y no se porque no me esta funcionando.

```
#include <iostream>

class MemoryError : public std::runtime_error{
public:
    MemoryError(const std::string &method)
        : std::runtime_error("[EXCEPTION] the size is too big or is less than zero - "+method)
    {}

    void show() const{
        std::cerr<<this->what()<<"\n\nPress Enter to continue. . .";
        std::cin.ignore();
    }
};

void try_resize(int size){
    int *array = new(std::nothrow) int[size];

    if(array == nullptr) throw MemoryError("try_resize(int size)");

    std::cout<<"Has reservado un array de "<<size<<" espacios\n";

    delete [] array;
}

int main(){

    try{

        try_resize(-1);

    }catch(const MemoryError &ex){
        ex.show();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

como se ve en el codigo estoy intentando reservar memoria con tamaño -1 esto hace que new falle y devuelva un `nullptr` ese nulo es capturado por un if y lanza la excepcion `MemoryError` pero eso no pasa.

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Parece ser que hay algun *bug* en la librería usada por tu compilador: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59414654/8663418

Comment: Puedes llamar explícitamente tu sobrecarga: `::operator new[]`.

Comment: Para dar algo de luz, mira lo siguiente: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444311/nothrow-not-working-even-with-correct-header-gcc-c#comment108692878_61444311 https://stackoverflow.com/a/37516653/13419694